# Unable to save Managed object context

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a **Folder** entity and a **Planner** entity with a note attribute, they have a To One relationship. I am trying to add a default Planner with every Folder and save some default text for the note property value.

So basically After creating a folder, tapping on it should open the note to edit and save. but I cannot seem to add a default planner when creating a new folder. I am unsure where I am going wrong, at the moment trying to display the `folder.planner.note` leads to a crash - with no error, which means the folder has no planner.

**[UPDATE]** Originally I had not created a relation between the folder and planner. After doing so another error has occurred so post has moved.

Here is the code when creating the folder:

```
 //Add new folder
 //Get the context
     let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
 //get entity details
     let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Folder", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)
 //Create the managed object to be inserted
     let folder = Folder(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc!)

        //Error
         var error: NSError?
            if moc!.save(nil){}

        //Storing Data
        folder.title = folderName.text
        folder.details = folderDetails.text
        folder.date = folderDate.date

        //Add Default Planner Note to Folder

        //Get entity details
        let entityPlanner = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Planner", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)

        //Create the managed object to be inserted
        let planner = Planner(entity: entityPlanner!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc!)

        //Add Text

        planner.notes = "Default text"

        //add planner to folder just added 

        folder.planner = planner

        //Insert the new note into the folder planner

        var folderPlanner = folder.planner    
        folderPlanner.notes = planner.notes 

    moc?.save(&error)
```

Comment: Are you trying to confuse us? Did you have `folder.planner = planner` initially in your code or added you that just now? And  what is `event`? It is nowhere defined in your code.

Comment: Sorry my braodband keeps cutting out whilst upgrading, sorry I was updating it now to give you a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set a relationship between the `folder` and the `planner`
object. You have to set either

```
folder.planner = planner
```

or

```
planner.folder = folder
```

Comment: I seemed to have overlooked that part, however I am not getting an error of Unrecognised selector sent to instance for the following lines, `var eventPlanner = event.planner`  /  `eventPlanner.notes = planner.notes`

Comment: @JUSDEV: It is unclear to me why you have these lines at all. Just set the relationship between the two objects, that should be all.

Comment: Yeah, it was unnecessary repetition, the error is now just falling to the `moc?.save(&error)`. Have to uninstall the app and reinstall to keep testing.

Comment: @JUSDEV: So you have an error when saving the context, but you don't tell us the error message? You don't make it easy to help you ...

Comment: The error is `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[testapp.Planner count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`.